# Wait before start new loop at FOR - JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'll let you see first what i got:

[**CODE**](http://jsfiddle.net/a16m4ph6/1/)

I decided to experiment and make a script which order numbers in an array in every possible way.

The first way I'm doing is the `"Selection mode"`, where you find the lower value of the array and you put it at the first position. As you can see I printed it into a table to make it funnier, but here comes my question, i want to put a delay at the end of every loop, where i highlight the values that I'm going to exchange, but for some reason it just organize all the table and then render it instead of going step by step.

---

Now I'm going to proceed to explain a bit my code ^^u:

If you click at "Restart" you'll get a new bunch of random numbers, and if you click at "Selection" the array will become ordered.

Functions:

- `generate`: generate `i` numbers with a value from `0` to `j`.
- `prinTable`: print the table.
- `renderDots`: adds styles at the dots which match with the array values.
- `seleccion`: execute the "Selection" way to organize the array.
- `highlight`: adds styles at the dots which will be exchanged at **THIS** loop, and remove highlight styles of the others points.

**I would like to get an affect like this:**

[image]

Comment: can't you use setTimeout ?

Comment: if u want to delay the content for loop, place the content of for loop inside a function and call that function inside for loop with setTimeout.

Comment: It don't works either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `setInterval` function instead of a `for` loop:

```
function seleccion(table){
  var ordenados = 0;
  var timer = setInterval(renderOneStep, 300)

  function renderOneStep(){
    if (ordenados < table.length){

      // do all the calculations

      ordenados++;
    } else {
      clearInterval(timer);
    }
  }
}
```

The `renderOneStep` function updates one column. It is called every 300ms.

Please see the updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a16m4ph6/4/).